# Ruby editing with intellisense

Tags: ruby, ide, refactoring, editor, intellisense

Currently I am exploring the world of ruby. Playing around in the irb you get nice intellisense for like `5.<tab><tab>`. I tried many editors/IDEs (mainly gedit, vim, radrails) with a couple of plugins. I kind of do not like the bloated eclipse-style environment but as far as I found out it is the only one providing intellisense.
All I have found for gedit/vim (never tried emacs, actually I cannot remember anyone using emacs for ruby development) are plugins doing completion based on phrases in the same file.

Is there some intellisenselike feature for an editor? In my job I am developing PHP in Eclipse PDT but I would really like to not use a bloated IDE for ruby :)

Comment: irb knows which methods 5 has because it's interpreter. but I hope no IDE will interpret my code continuously

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Rubymine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/index.html). Its three killer features are Intellisense, Refactoring and Debugging.

Comment: Not really what I was looking for but looks nice, I will give it a try.